# Could not load type "Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\Type\CaptchaType"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle 1.1 & Symfony 2.3.42. I configured my form like this:

```
$builder->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('password', 'password')
        ->add('captcha', CaptchaType::class);
```

This error comes up:

> Could not load type "Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\Type\CaptchaType"

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle), thats the right way to configure the captcha field.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run into the same problem. First of all: `Gregwar\CaptchaBundle` does support Symfony >= 2.8 in its 1.x versions. If you using Symfony < 2.8 the documentation won't help you, because parsing the class as element type is not supported. The documentation helps if you are using Symfony => 2.8.

#### Gregwar/CaptchaBundle 1.* + Symfony < 2.8 use:

```
$builder->add('captcha', 'captcha');
```

#### Gregwar/CaptchaBundle 2.* + Symfony => 2.8 use:

```
$builder->add('captcha', CaptchaType::class);
```

... to define your form captcha input.